# Mac unity not working (error message)

Tags: unity, macos

Upon opening a new project or template the unity launcher dies and shows the error message:

```
Could not find Unity Package Manager local server application at 
[/Applications/Unity/Hub/Editor/2020.3.15f1/Unity.app/Contents/Resources/PackageManager/Server/UnityPackageManager]. 
Missing files could be the result of an antivirus action or a corrupt Unity installation.
```

If I diagnose it says

```
❓ UPM health check (UNKNOWN)
Start the UPM process and call its health endpoint
>> Could not find UPM executable at path '/Applications/Unity/Hub/Editor/2020.3.15f1/Unity.app/Contents/Resources/PackageManager/Server/UnityPackageManager'
```

Anyone that cane help it would be greatly appreciated

Comment: The message says that there are missing/corrupt files in the Unity installation. Something/someone messed with the files. Have you tried to remove Unity and do clean install?

Answer (score 1):

I had that problem yesterday, and I solved it by uninstalling Unity and reinstalling it.